# Automatically increasing `\rightskip` in difficult paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex

Let's say I want to set text ragged right, but not preventing hyphenation, and thus, say

`\rightskip=0pt plus 4em`

(or using `ragged2e` and other similar packages for a little bit more flexibility, for simplicity here I will only use the most basic parameters to show the problem I am facing)

However, this will occasionally leads to overfull box. I want to prevent overfull boxes without raising tolerance to terribly high. And thus say, I use `\emergencystretch`. Now, in the third pass, a somewhat "imaginary" stretch is added to problematic lines. However, this will lead to underfull box.

What I really want is that, if TeX is unable to make the paragraph, I would like it to temporarily increase `\rightskip` stretchability. That is, I would rather that occasionally a few paragraphs are a little bit more "ragged" than usual. I can do this manually. However, is there any possible way to do this automatically? or other means to achieve similar effect? I am using LuaTeX, so lua-based solutions is also acceptable.

Example,

```
\hsize=1in
\rightskip=0pt plus 0.5em % for demonstration purpose only
\overfullrule=1ex
% \emergencystretch=0.5in

A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel
the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls
like mine.

\end
```

This will give overfull box,
[image]

add the commented out line,

```
\emergencystretch=0.5in
```

We get under full box,

[image]

*An imperfect solution*
based on http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Post_linebreak_filter

```
\directlua{
  function mclass_ragged (head)
    for line in node.traverse_id(node.id("hlist"), head) do
      if line.glue_order == 0 then
        line.list = node.hpack(line.list)
      end
    end
    return head
  end

  luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "post_linebreak_filter", mclass_ragged, "mclass_ragged")

}

\rightskip=0pt plus 2em
\dim_set:Nn\emergencystretch{0.5\textwidth}
```

This will results in small "overfullbox" if a shrieked line is set to natural width. However, I think in a ragged setting, it is hardly noticeable. And even word space is better. (Or otherwise, one can kill the shrinkability first)

It somehow interfere with `titletoc` and `hyperref`. Since I use `\filright` to set toc entries totally ragged anyway, so I only add the call back after toc. In particular, I hooked it into may `\mainmatter` definition.

Comment: Add, at the end of the paragraph, `{\rightskip=0pt plus 8em\par}` (or whatever is needed for the particular paragraph. Note the braces, that keep the setting local.

Comment: @egreg I know I can do this manually. But I am thinking if there's a way to instruct TeX to do this automatically whenever it cannot produce a paragraph without overfull box.

Comment: as always it would be easier to test answers if you provided an example test file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an example. Basically, I would like `\emergencystretch` to effectively added towards `\rightskip` stretch instead of distributed along the line

Comment: TeX does three passes (if `\emergencystretch` is positive, otherwise just two). It never seizes the initiative and changes the parameters.

Comment: @egreg but luatex could, probably, but perhaps not this evening, (save the hlist prior to line breaking, and if it ends overfull discard it and linebreak with different stretchier \rightskip)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That sounds exactly like what I am looking for. I am still going through LuaTeX's manual looking for this. LuaTeX has gone a very long way but its manual is no more instructive than years ago. (or it's just me too unfamiliar with it)

Comment: When I read your question, I too thought of the same approach suggested by @DavidCarlisle; that is entirely doable in TeX, it doesn’t require LuaTeX.  However, I cannot answer this evening either, sorry (surely somebody else will… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks, can you give a hint? For example what parameters I shall look for.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti you could do it in tex if you grab each para in a vbox, but luatex would allow it on the main vertical list (probably)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I understood correctly, one way is to hook to the pre line break filter callback. And successively call Tex.linebreak until there's no overfull box, by increasing rightskip at each call

Comment: @YanZhou basically something like that but it's gone midnight so not tried any details:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I worked out a way. 1) Set emergency stretch to a fairly high number, and 2) use the `post_linebreak_filter` to set each line to its natural width. This way, there will actually be small "overfull boxes", but only if the original line was shrieked. So amount will be fairly small. And unnoticeable in a ragged setting. If desired, we can always only change lines that are stretched.

Comment: @YanZhou it would be good if you could post an answer, there are not so many examples of lua callbacks on the site.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am still trying to figure some issues. Occasionally I am getting errors "'endlink' ended up in different nesting level than 'startlink". Which I believe has something to do with hyperref. Somehow, they are interfering each other.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have to recant my statement that this can be done with pure TeX.  Althought it is pretty easy, redefining `\par` and `\everypar`, to set up things so that the contents of each paragraph are captured in a `\hbox`, which is then repeatedly broken into lines inside a `\vbox` with different settings of `\rightskip`, I realized that TeX offers practically no provision for knowing whether an overfull `\hbox` has occured during the paragraphing (`\badness` will report a value of `1000000` only if the overfull `\hbox` happens to be the last line of the paragraph).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti welcome to my world:-) (as long as there are no non-removable items you can inspect each line by hand via \lastbox but it's harder than it could have been)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that would work with any tex engine, and less likely to interfere with other packages than using the lua callbacks would be to freeze the interword space (plain TeX's `\raggedright` does this as does the ragged2e version).

When combined with `\emergencystretch` this means that all the extra space goes at the right, so in the example below, while the like `of my entire` is technically underfull, it does not appear over-streteched rather the line is just shorter (more ragged) than the `\rightskip` parameter allows.

[image]